# Deploy console app from Azure Devops (cloud version) to a machine with a Microsoft-provided host agent (Failed to create PSDrive with destination...)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, agent

I want to deploy a console application from Azure Devops (cloud version) to a machine (VPN protected) where I installed a Microsoft-provided host agent.

It is working fine for web applications, where I used the release pipeline task '**IIS web app deploy**'.

I could deploy my console application using the same task, which I tried with success, but it would look weird, because my IIS would recognize a console app as a web app:

[image: Not the right way to deploy a console app]

Although this solution would work, as I could still 'explore the folder' and launch my console application executable, it is not a professional solution.

What I want is to copy the executable to my server's shared folder.

In order to do so I selected the release pipeline task '**Windows Machine File Copy**' with the following options:

[image: Windows Machine File Copy Task Options]

I must say that I shared the right folder which is accessible to all computers inside my VPN.

Everything looks good to me, but clearly there's a problem as I have the following error:

**> Failed to Create PSDrive with Destination:

> '\srvdevrct01\GdmUtilitaires', ErrorMessage: 'The network path was
>   not found'**

What am I missing?

Comment: Which agent engine type this windows machine file copy task used and you encountered the issue? Deployment group? If yes, did you ever try to use private agent to do that? I mean install the self agent into one machine which locate in same domain with server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already installed the Azure Pipelines agent to target server, might I suggest creating a deployment group and re-configuring the agent to be part of that?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml.

More information on deployment groups can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops

In general, if you are running the agent on the target server with sufficent rights, you don't have to rely on WinRM-based tasks, but can run a normal copy task like this: That way you don't have to rely on WinRM-based tasks, but run normal copy like

Comment: I am already using a deployment group but I have more than 1 agent installed on my target machine. Do you believe that can be a problem?

Comment: If you have multiple agents assigned to the same deployment group, you might want to use tags to separate the agents (and consequently use the same tags in your release definition/pipeline to target a certain agent). Otherwise every available agent in the deployment group will pick you deployment job. Multiple agents running in the same machine is not a problem as such.